# Delphi Tools VCL Style Designer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I use Delphi XE3,  but the `VCL Style Designer` menu item does not appear on the `Tools` menu.
How can I activate this `Tools` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XE3, the VCL Style Designer was given an FMX style export function and renamed the Bitmap Style Designer. If there isn't an entry for 'Bitmap Style Designer' under the Tools menu, add one following RRUZ's steps but using `BitmapStyleDesigner.exe` not `VCLStyleDesigner.exe` for the program name.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the entry was deleted accidentally. To create the item again go to  Tools->Configure Tools-> Add and then fill the Tools property window like so.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatly on my `bin` folder, there is not such file `VCLStyleDesigner.exe`, there is instead the file VCLStyleViewer.exe`, wich I figure that is not what I need. I wonder how this could happen...

Comment: Then check for a copy in the  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\Redist\win32` directory,

Comment: Same as in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\bin`.